# Google app engine os.path functions not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, os.path

I am seeing a strange and frustrating behavior in Google App Engine. I am launching google app engine from a particular folder like this: (dev_appserver .) In this folder I have a folder called data with a few subfolders under it (one of them is json_folder which contains a file temp.json). From inside my main python src that contains the MainHandler class I do this:

```
 print os.getcwd(), os.path.isfile("data/json_folder/temp.json")
```

It prints the expected cwd and False even though the json_folder/temp.json exists and if I launch a regular python shell from the same directory it correctly prints True. Why does it work in regular Python but not in GAE python?

I also tried the following. I walk through my current dir and list the subfolders under data but the isdir() returns false even for directories! Why is python thinking they are not directories? ls -al shows them to be directories it makes no sense:
(this prints json_folder, False as one of the outputs, all subfolders are returning False):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("data"): 
   for file in files: 
      print file, os.path.isdir(file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) the path, it works if you only use files from the cwd as you are in the same directory as the file, once you hit a file folder outside the cwd you are checking if the file from that outside directory is a file in your cwd, you also want `isfile` to check for files:

```
 print file, os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, file))
```

If you want to check for directories you need to iterate over dirs not files:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("data"): 
   for _dir in dirs: 
          print _dir, os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, _dir)
```

Comment: I still don't understand why it works in a regular python shell. Using that I made a workaround for now.